# Glossy reflection using Principled BSDF is much rougher, why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Here's an example with the simplest possible node setup:

[image]

For some reason, all glossy materials using the Principled BSDF are super rough when viewed in a mirror.

I'm using Blender 2.79. Have I encountered a bug or am I completely missing something else?

I'm using the Cycles Renderer with a GTX 1070.

The blend file is here: https://i.peterwunder.de/mirror_test.blend

Comment: What do you mean by "viewed in a mirror." ?

Comment: I have added the information above. I couldn't share the original file since it was well over 400 MB, so I created a new one that exhibits the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Too much Glossy Filtering

As said in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html):

> When using a value higher than 0.0, this will **blur** glossy reflections after blurry bounces, to reduce noise at the cost of accuracy. 1.0 is a good starting value to tweak.

You are using a value of 4.0, that means you are **strongly** using the filtering for glossy bounces.

[image]

Use a lower values to lower the strenght of the blur applied.

---

That said, actually the principled glossy shader behaves quite differently in comparison with the mere glossy shader in the sensitivity of the filtering.

Comment: I would never have guessed that this was the culprit. Thank you!